# Docker build requirements.txt not found (LINUX WSL)

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using LINUX WSL in my Windows 10 system to build docker image but always encounter error:

```
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
```

I have already included `COPY` command inside the dockerfile to copy everything (including the requirements.txt) to the `/app` directory. This thing always happens when I directly instruct the `docker build` command without copying the repository folder from the Windows 10 host to the LINUX WSL (using /mnt directory to locate where is the dockerfile in the host system).
However, if I copy the repository folder to the WSL first, it works without problem. I attached the dockerfile below,

```
#get python
FROM python:3.7

#install odbc unix distribution
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    unixodbc-dev \
    unixodbc \
    libpq-dev 

#set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the rest of the working directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . . 
 
# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: As a quick check, you can add `RUN ls` to see the content of your folder after the `COPY` command, just to verify that everything is there as it's supposed to be.

Comment: Docker has something called a "context", which is normal cases is the same root directory your Dockerfile resides in. COPY commands only work with files or directories already located in your context. There are some ways around this (assgining different context) but these are mostly very convoluted. Make sure when building to always have the files in the correct context.